# TemplateBinding: The member <> is not recognized or is not accessible

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm new to C#, windows apps store and I'm struggling with a problem. I want to implement some template control which consist of a popup with a progress ring and a text.

In the Template class (CustomProgressRing.cs) I want to be able to manipulate the enclosed popup and it's properties. 
I succeeded with the TextBlock by setting it's Text prop as TempalteBinding, so in the class I am able to access the TextBlock's Text property.
I want to apply the TemplateBinding to the IsOpen prop of the popup, but I get the error: 
 `The member "IsOpen" is not recognized or is not accessible`

Below is the xaml:

```
 <Style TargetType="local:CustomProgressRingPopup">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomProgressRingPopup">
                        <Border
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                            <Popup x:Name="ProgressRingPopup" x:Uid="LoggingInWaitingPopup" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsOpen}">
                                <Grid x:Name="gdChild" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Background="#969696" >
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="LoginProgressRingText" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" FontSize="20" Margin="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Popup>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Here is the CustomProgressRing.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Documents;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using System.Diagnostics;

// The Templated Control item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234235

namespace QSTLibrary.WIN8.Tools
{
    public sealed class CustomProgressRingPopup : Control
    {
        public CustomProgressRingPopup()
        {
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomProgressRingPopup);
        }



        public string Text
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Text.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register(
                    "Text", 
                    typeof(string), 
                    typeof(CustomProgressRingPopup), 
                    new PropertyMetadata("Void", new PropertyChangedCallback(OnTextChanged)));



        private void ProgressRingPopup_Opened(object sender, object e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Popup opened");
        }

        private static void OnTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) 
        {
            CustomProgressRingPopup instance = d as CustomProgressRingPopup;
            if (instance != null)
            {
                string newValue = e.NewValue as string;
                instance.Text = newValue;
                //instance.IsOpen = true; - not working
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Why I can't set templateBinding to the IsOpen prop of the Popup?

Comment: Can you post the definition for your CustomProgressRingPopup class?

Comment: CustomProgressRingPopup has IsOpen dependency property defined? is it deriving Popup?

Comment: @Moozhe - I've posted the class definition

Comment: @nit - CustomProgressRingPopup has no dependency property defined. Please the class in my post. I've edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are deriving your `CustomProgressRingPopup` from `Control` that is the reason you are not getting `IsOpen` property. You should  define your own Dependancy property IsOpen in CustomProgressRingPopup to handle it, which is bit of the work.

```
Template binding searches the Property in the control that is being templated.
```

Comment: Why I was able to set the template binding to the Text property(look at the TextBlock in xaml)? It was because I set the dependancy to the text property in the .cs file? Maybe I should proceed with the IsOpen just like with the Text property...If I extend Popup instead of Control I will be still able to use the CustomProgressRingPopup as a template aobject? Sry for this noob questions but I need to finish something in a very short time. (I'm a java programmer(Android) and I need to handle something in Windows app)

Comment: Yes, you have Text DP in your control thats why you can template bind it. Extending the Popup would not be a good idea in this case as you are templating it.. and Popup does not have Template property exposed.. so better go with creating the DP.. i have updated the answer

Comment: I've added the dp in the class and now I am able to set template binding in xaml, but it crashes at launch and I've got the error: "failed to assign to property "Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.Popup.IsOpen". Maybe I'm not allowed to use the IsOpen as a dependancy.

Comment: Can you try IsOpen="{Binding IsOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomProgressRingPopup}}}" instead of templatebinding

Comment: I've tried this, but I've got the errors: "The property "AncestorType" is not recognized or is not accessible." and "The property "AncestorType" was not found in type "RelativeSource"."

Comment: this is weird... :) RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}... is it also giving you error?

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I'm able to use IsOpen and works. I managed to open the popup. Now a last question: I need to show a popup with a progress ring and a text in the middle of the screen. Was a good approach using TemplatedControl or whould be better to use UserControl? I need the reference to this popup from the code, to open popup programtically by calling IsOpen (works now with your help). Thanks for your precious help :).

Comment: I will suggest you to create the usercontrol with all the controls inside and place that user control inside the Popup instead of creating the control and templating it with popup... you can then directly open/close that popup... secondly since you will be using usercontrol you can bind the properties of your controls in it with the viewmodel properties increasing the testing scope

Comment: OK, so I will create a user control containing the progressRing and a textBlock and will add that into a popup defined in the page's XAML. It's become simple now....thanks